# AppleScript Syntax Error

Tags: applescript

For some reason, when I attempt to run this code in AppleScript, I get the following error:

> Syntax Error
>
> Expected end of line but found “"”.

Here is the troubled portion of my code:

```
if a = "911" then tell application "System Events" 
    kestroke "a" using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```

Comment: I think you might have an error in the latter part of your code, you say `kestroke` but I think you mean `keystroke`

Comment: You have a typo in line 2. Use `keystroke` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `keystroke` instead of kestroke